# SwiftUI: Resource initialization failed first time code is executed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a function that searches for text in a scanned document. The first time the function is executed I get the following error:

*020-06-27 14:43:19.584321+0100 Foo[58201:3904738] Resource initialization failed: could not open file /System/Library/LinguisticData/RequiredAssets_en.bundle/AssetData/en.lm/variants.dat*

The function is:

```
    func recognizeText(
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping ([String], [UIImage]) -> Void) {
    print ("Log 1")
    queue.async {
        let uiImages = (0..<self.cameraScan.pageCount).compactMap({
            self.cameraScan.imageOfPage(at: $0) })
        let images = uiImages.compactMap{$0.cgImage}

        print ("Log 2")
        let imagesAndRequests = images.map({ (image: $0,
            request: VNRecognizeTextRequest()) })

        print ("Log 3")
        let textPerPage = imagesAndRequests.map { image,
            request -> String in
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, options: [:])
            print ("Log 4")
            do {
                print ("Log 5")
                try handler.perform([request])
                guard let observations = request.results as? 
                    [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else { return "" }
                print ("Log 6")
                return observations.compactMap({
                  $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string }).joined(separator: "\n")
            } catch {
                print(error)
                print ("Log 7")
                return ""
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print ("Log 8")
            completionHandler(textPerPage, uiImages)
        }
    }
}
```

On first execution text is match correctly but the log shows:

*DocumentCameraViewController() called
Log 1
Log 2
Log 3
Log 4
Log 5
2020-06-27 14:43:19.584321+0100 Foo[58201:3904738] Resource initialization failed: could not open file /System/Library/LinguisticData/RequiredAssets_en.bundle/AssetData/en.lm/variants.dat
2020-06-27 14:43:19.595998+0100 Foo[58201:3904738] Resource initialization failed: could not open file /System/Library/LinguisticData/RequiredAssets_en.bundle/AssetData/en.lm/variants.dat
2020-06-27 14:43:19.600817+0100 Foo[58201:3904738] Resource initialization failed: could not open file /System/Library/LinguisticData/RequiredAssets_en.bundle/AssetData/en.lm/variants.dat
2020-06-27 14:43:19.605562+0100 Foo[58201:3904738] Resource initialization failed: could not open file /System/Library/LinguisticData/RequiredAssets_en.bundle/AssetData/en.lm/variants.dat
Log 6*

On subsequent executions no errors are logged.

I have no idea how to resolve the issue as no errors are directly reported to my function.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have the same issue but it doesn't that there is any solution for this nor does as anyone else have this error

Comment: No - but the code does appear to work even with the warning/error message. I have read that the new 'SwiftUI 2' for Ios14 has fixed a lot of the bugs in SwiftUI

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems to work despite the errors and those can be ignored. Thanks for the reply